# ypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: xlwings

I have error if trying to do example 
http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html

```
 ---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python3\mymodule.py", line 7, in rand_numbers

    n = int(Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value)  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'



Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Could you please add some code example to your question?

Comment: there are not any new. all code lines from ur example.

Comment: I bet you have an empty Cell B1 - put in a number a suggested by the comment

Comment: >>  
I bet you have an empty Cell B1 - put in a number a suggested by the comment
------------------------------------------------

Yeah! you are right ! All works ! )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the error occurred due to absence value in the cell. Try to check if the value is `None` before conversion to int.